# Terminal window title vs Git branch name in the command prompt?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scripting, terminal

I wanted to add information about Git branch to my command line prompt, and I found [this post](https://coderwall.com/p/fasnya/add-git-branch-name-to-bash-prompt):

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

I added those lines into my `.bashrc`.

It works, shows the Git branch in the prompt (`joedoe@machine1 ~/git/repo1 (dev_branch) $` ), however, it messes up my GNOME Terminal's window title, which used to contain current working directory, and now it just says "Terminal."

Why did this change the terminal window title?
Is there a better solution?

Comment: What was the previous value of `$PS1` before your change?

Comment: It was `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the old $PS1 sets the title:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]
```

The `\[...\]` part just means the characters inside don't change the length of the prompt. `\e]0;...\a` is used to set the title, the title was set to `\u@\h: \w` which translates to *username@hostname: workdir*.

Include the pattern into your new PS1 to get the same behaviour.